# Return JSONP in proper format WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-services, jsonp

I'm trying to output a correctly wrapped JSONP value for jQuery to consume.

The output I'm looking for is:

```
jsoncallback({"Status": "OK"})
```

But the atm it's outputting:

```
"jsoncallback({"Status": "OK"})"
```

Evidently this is not in correct JSONP format as the jQuery request can't handle the response.

My OperationContract in C# is:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   UriTemplate = "returndata?s={s}")]
Stream EchoWithGet(string s);

    public string EchoWithGet(string s)
    {
        string json = @"jsoncallback({'Status':'OK'})";
        Console.WriteLine("Call Made: " + s);
        return json;
    }
```

I've tried using `JSON.NET` and also the `System.Web.Script` Namespace to use the `JavaScriptSerializer`.

But nothing is working for me all I actually want to do is get rid of two double quotes.

Comment: what's wpf got to do with this?

Comment: I'm using the WPF environment, so I want to cater to that. Normally I'd end up getting answers related to ASP where it wouldn't help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're submitting an ajax request with jQuery and asks for `dataType: "jsonp"`, jQuery will pass a name for the callback function in the request (e.g., `/returndata?s=hello&callback=jquery123456789`), so returning a constant "jsonCallback" will not work in that case.

Also, in your question you have the operation contract definition returning `Stream`, while on the operation itself you're returning `string` - something is wrong there.

What you need to do: you have two options. The first one is to let WCF handle the JSONP padding for you. Your operation would need to return a data type with a property "Status", and just return it. You'd also need to enable the [`CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.crossdomainscriptaccessenabled.aspx) property on the WebHttpBinding used by your endpoint. Your operation would look something like the code below:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public class Service
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "returndata?s={s}")]
    public MyType ReturnData(string s)
    {
        return new MyType { Status = "OK" };
    }
}
```

The second option, if you want to create the JSONP code yourself, would be to take an additional parameter in the URI for the callback function name, then use it when creating your response. You'd also need to return it as a `Stream`, so that you don't get the response as a string (which is probably what you have right now). That would look like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class Service
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "ReturnData?s={s}&callback={callbackFunctionName}")]
    public Stream EchoWithGet(string s, string callbackFunctionName)
    {
        string jsCode = callbackFunctionName + "({\"Status\":\"OK\"});";
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/javascript";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsCode));
    }
}
```

And this jQuery code can be used to access this service:

```
    function StackOverflow_11090835_Test() {
        var url = "/StackOverflow_11090835.svc/ReturnData";
        var data = { s: "Hello world" };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#result").text(result.Status);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this could be the problem I'm facing, and sorry about the Stream DataType error, it was actually a mistake as I was playing around with code. I'll give this a try tonight and see what happens. Thanks again

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot, after 10 hours of research I've finally managed it.

Comment: I don't understand the first option. How does WCF handle the JSONP padding for you? And why does the binding require `CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled` but option 2 doesn't?

Comment: In the first option, once you enable `CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled`, the WCF formatter will see if the request has a `callback=<name>` query parameter; if it does, then it will wrap the response in a `<name>(` and `);` pair.

Answer (score 1):

You need to eval the output from your WCF call.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/7B2EL/).

You're getting a string back from your WCF call.  You essentially need to compile it and then execute it.

Here's the code from the fiddle:

```
function jsonCallback(obj){
    alert(obj.Status);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var js = "jsonCallback({'Status':'OK'})";
    eval(js);
});​
```

The `js` variable is your output from the WCF call.  As soon as I `eval` it, it will compile and execute.

Comment: Hi thanks for the hints but I don't believe that answers my question as the `"jsoncallback({"Status": "OK"})"` isn't even being looked at by jQuery