# Move location of JSONP WCF callback parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, wcf, jsonp

I'm trying to configure my web service that the callback parameter is a prefix instead of a suffix of the call. The reason i want to change this is because some of the pre-built telerik components that I'm using call it with the callback as a prefix.

```
[JavascriptCallbackBehavior(UrlParameterName = "callback")]
public class Service : IService { }
```

Here is my service contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "updatedata/models={inRecords_}")]
    CurrentBatch[] UpdateData(string inRecords_);
```

Right now when I call it, i call it like

```
http://localhost:8000/Service/console/json/currentbatch/updatedata/models=myModelsHere?callback=myCallBack
```

But how I really want to call it is like (but as of right now i get a 404 saying endpoint not found)

```
 http://localhost:8000/Service/console/json/currentbatch/updatedata/?callback=myCallBack&models=MyModelsHere
```

I even tried changing the service contract property to something like

```
        UriTemplate = "updatedata/&models={inRecords_}")]
```

But i still keep getting a 404, saying that the endpoint is not found.

What can i do to fix this so that my callback parameter gets prefixed and I can call it like.

```
http://localhost:8000/Service/console/json/currentbatch/updatedata/?callback=myCallBack&models=MyModelsHere
```

The MSDN Page gives no information about changing the order either.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.javascriptcallbackbehaviorattribute.urlparametername(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.javascriptcallbackbehaviorattribute.urlparametername%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up removing

```
[JavascriptCallbackBehavior(UrlParameterName = "callback")]
```

Changing the service contracts to

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "/?callback={callback}&models={rec}")]
    Stream InsertData(string callback, string rec);
```

and then outputting the stream like;

```
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/javascript";
        string serialized = JSONSerializationHelper.Serialize<CurrentBatch[]>(new CurrentBatch[] { new CurrentBatch() { GroupName = "hello" } });
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(callback+ "(" + serialized + ");"));
```

[Return JSONP in proper format WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090835/return-jsonp-in-proper-format-wcf)

Thank you to the unhelpful guy who downvoted my legitimate question...