# JSON parse error callback was not called in AJAX request to WCF service

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have created a WCF Service and uploaded to a server and s up and running fine. The problem is when I try to access it via an ajax request.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
 void UploadPic(string imageData);

public void UploadPic(string imageData)
        {
            try { 
                string Pic_Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("MyPicture.png");
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Pic_Path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                    {
                        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                        bw.Write(data);
                        bw.Close();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            }

        }
```

The ajax request is being done from another domain, so I'm using jsonp so the request doesn't gets block by CORS issues.
But I'm getting this specific error Error: jQuery110107099825242048435_1423163196150 was not called. My ajax call is like this:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://g9w2493g.houston.hp.com/marketing/David/Service1.svc/UploadPic',
                data: {imageData: dataURL},//'{ "imageData" : "' + dataURL + '" }',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                jsonp: 'jsonp',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (jsonData) {
                   var data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
               },
                error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   console.log(request.responseText);
                   console.log(textStatus);
                   console.log(errorThrown);
               }
            });
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem or is someone has experience the same error. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is the endpoint serving correct jsonp?

Comment: How do I check that ? The configuration of the UploadPic method is above. Thanks  for your help.

Comment: [This SO post might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090835/return-jsonp-in-proper-format-wcf)

Comment: I already have tried that, it returns the same error, but it appended a SyntaxError: missing ; before statement {"Status":"OK"}.

Comment: Oh man, ahi implemented again the solution in the link you posted, and changed the jsonp: "jsonp" to jsonp: "callback" and now its working, thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! Happy to have helped.