# Calling JQuery Ajax goes to success, but data undefined

Tags: jquery, wcf

Currently, I am using the **JQuery Ajax** command to call a **WCF Service** called isValidUser.  Using chrome to debug, I can see that the WCF Service is sending what appears to be the correct JSON Response back. The success callback method defined in the **JQuery** is also getting called.  However, the alert message is outputting 'Undefined.'

Below is the snippet of the Client script that I used.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://localhost:28506/VikingServices.svc/isValidUser/john/doe',
    processData: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "callback",
    success: callback,
    error: ServiceFailed
});
function callback(data) {
    alert(data);
}
function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.responseText) {
        var err = xhr.responseText;
        if (err)
            error(err);
        else
            error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
    }
    return;
}
```

This is the response that I see in the Chrome Developer tools response from the Ajax Request:

```
{"Name":"Super Admin","Username":"john","id":1}
```

1. Is there any reason I can see a correct response in **Chrome Dev Tools**, but not get any info in the success callback of JQuery? Is it a JQuery Error?
2. Is there any additional info I can get from JQuery or another way I can format the **data** variable? It seem that it should simply output the JSON object that I am seeing in the **Chrome Dev Tools**.
3. Are there any trivial format issues with the JSON Object I have received in the **Chrome Dev Tools**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datatype is 'jsonp', therefore your response must be a valid jsonp response. Something like

```
callback({"Name":"Super Admin","Username":"john","id":1});
```

Should work. There is also a validator: http://json-p.org/validator.html

Comment: I did change my code to wrap it at the level of the WCF. However, there are 2 different approaches found here to help to get to it to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090835/return-jsonp-in-proper-format-wcf